# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser: How to remove <font> tags from script output?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, tags

I'm using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm) to extract a list of URLs from a page as follows:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'http://www.domain.com/';
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('table[width=370]') as $table)
    {
    foreach($table->find('a') as $item)
        echo $item->outertext . '<br><hr>';
    }
$html->clear();
?>
```

It works just fine insofar as it extracts the required information, however, **some** of the a tags (on domain.com) are formatted like this:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com"><font size="2">Anchor text</font></a>
```

Whereas, in others, the font size is defined in the p tag that contains each a tag, meaning the a tag is displayed as:

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com">Anchor text</a>
```

Is there any way to strip out the font tag from those a tags that have it? It's probably very simple, but I've been 'running around in rings' for ages trying to do it :(

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions you might have.

Tom.

Answer (score 3):

[strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) maybe?

If you only want to allow the `a` tag, just use:

```
echo strip_tags($item->outertext, 'a');
```

Comment: Ah, yes - thanks for that! I knew it was something pretty simple :) I modified it to: `echo strip_tags($item->outertext, '<a>') . '<br><hr>';`, which worked perfectly.